# FLV/MP4 player that allows only rewind but not skip forward?

Tags: wordpress, video

I have an online video presentation with no control bar, to avoid people skipping important parts of the explanation, and then asking me later what was in the video.
Problem is, if something happens and you loose attention for some seconds, you cant go back.

So, I want a player where you can play, pause/resume, rewind, but cannot go forward.

I currently use JWPlayer (could not find any config option to do that), but I am open to any alternatives that could be hosted in my wordpress site.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't think that you will find a player with the feature you requesting per default, since `FF` is a pretty basic feature.

One approach is to download [ffmpeg](http://www.ffmpeg.org/) and to build the player and in the player code disable the key-mapping for 'FF'. The player that uses [SDL](http://www.libsdl.org/) is pretty basic...

Comment: missed the part about the hosting...

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I will keep the question open for a few more days (hope) :)